# Hijack the windows scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html

This may seem like an odd question but I need to know if it's possible to hijack the window scrollbar so when a user scrolls it it doesn't scroll the page. I want to write some js that instead when the user scrolls the window scrollbar it scrolls a div. I can write the js to detect the scrolls and how much to animate the div etc but not sure how to hijack the window scrollbar and stop it scrolling the window Is this possible?

Comment: o.O it is pretty odd. I would recommend to place what shouldn't be scrolled with `position:fixed;`

Comment: It's not possible to "hijack" it but it is possible to position elements on the page using `position: fixed` so they don't scroll. It's impossible to give more info without seeing what you are trying to do

Comment: Just to mention: there are lots of existing scripts for this but nearly none of them work well with the popular Magic Mouse when momentum is enabled. They all suck.

Comment: @Radek: When did the Magic Mouse become popular?

Comment: @x3ro since the first they it came out. This happens to somewhat any Apple product. :)

Comment: @Radek: Well maybe its just over here in Germany, and I'm just guessing too, but I haven't seen many of them to date and I _think_ their not selling too well over here :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to "hijack" the browser window, you could try a number of other ways, such as:

## <- Overflow ---------------------------------------------------->

#### [css]:

```
<style>
html, body {
    overflow: none;
}
</style>
```

#### [javascript]:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onScroll, false);
window.onmousewheel = function onScroll(event) {
    // Use "event" to distinguish between up or down
    // for which you determine which way to scroll
    // the particular div you want.
}
</script>
```

## <- Preventing Default --------------------------------------->

#### [javascript (untested)]:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', onMouseWheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = onMouseWheel; // IE

function onMouseWheel(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.cancelBubble = true;

        // Use "event" to distinguish between up or down
        // for which you determine which way to scroll
        // the particular div you want.

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Both ways are a better approach. I think overflow method is very simple...actually they both are, great work